# What is the correct way of fetching elements by a list of IDs then displaying them on a listview? -Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

According to the documentation, we should avoid nesting data when it comes to database relationships. So I structured my data as follow:

```
{
  "rides": {
    "ride1": {
      "price": "500",
      "bids": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "bid1": true,
         "bid2": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "bids": {
    "bid1": {
      "price": "550",
      "ride": "ride1"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

In one page of my app, the user should be able to see all "bids" that are linked to the selected "ride" in a **ListView**. My attempt was: Getting the keys of the bids in an arrayList and then fetching the bids by key on by one. My problem is the fact that I have to display all the bids in a listview at once.

```
   bidsListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<String> bidskeysOfActiveRideArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Boolean IsbidLinkedToThisRid = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                    if (IsbidLinkedToThisRid) {
                        String bidObjectId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                        bidskeysOfActiveRideArrayList.add(bidObjectId);
                    }
                }
                fetchMultipleBidsByKeys(bidskeysOfActiveRideArrayList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        databaseReference.child("rides").child(ride.getID()).child("bids").addValueEventListener(bidsListener);
```

The two functions are here:

```
private void fetchMultipleBidsByKeys(ArrayList<String> bidskeysOfActiveRideArrayList) {
        ArrayList<Bid> bidsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String bid_id:bidskeysOfActiveRideArrayList){
            bidsArrayList.add(getBidByKey(bid_id));
        }
        displayBidList(bidsArrayList);
    }

    private Bid getBidByKey(String bidObjectId) {
        final Bid[] bidFetched = {null};
        ValueEventListener bidsSingleFetcher = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    bidFetched[0] = snapshot.getValue(Bid.class);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        databaseReference.child("bids").child(bidObjectId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(bidsSingleFetcher);
        return bidFetched[0];
    }
```

However, firebase data fetch is **asyncronuous**. So what is the correct way of fetching elements by a list of IDs then displaying them on a listview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve the asyncronuous behavoiur of `onDataChange()` method.